# nusoap_client->fault VS nusoap_client->getError()

Tags: php, nusoap

What's the diference between the field `fault` and the method `getError()` in nusoap class?

Can be posible to recover an error with `getError()` and the `fault` field to be empty?

I have seen some code like this one:

```
if($client->fault){
    //Do something
}else{
    $client->getError();
}
```

Can it be inside the else condition and get an error with that method?